# JMeter Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I made a test with JMeter and I made a regex which takes a `ticketid` from a response. That works when `loop count = 1`. But when `loop count = 2`, in next loop we have a new `ticketid`, but regex don't takes it and test fails. How make a regex which in every next loop takes a new `ticketid` that appears?

Comment: {"taskInfos":[{"model":{"ldap":false,"organizations":[{"ticket":{"ticketId":"4YESyxwCtA1Wj8ujUmCA18npTWF1uB/q"},"organizationName":"zziyulnnlk"},{"ticket":{"ticketId":"4YESyxwCtA0AdLTMy1KP28npTWF1uB/q"},"organizationName":"nzgpvivpba"}

Comment: Every next loop add a new ticketid and j made a regexr

Comment: Regexr:{"ticket":{"ticketId":"([^"]+)"},"organizationName":"${ORGANIZATION}"} where is "organization" used defined variables. When is loop count 1 work, but when is 2,3 ... then regexr dont takes ticketid

Comment: To be more precise. How made a regexr which takes last what appears in response ?

Comment: you must specify Match no and put into it the range of your last response parameter. Your question is not clear , it's written with a lot of disorder

Comment: Problem resolved, thanks on your time !!!

Comment: please put updates in the question rather than making people traipse through the comments to find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write java code using Beanshell Sampler to save extracted data to CSV file

- Extract your data using Regex Extractor
- See the sample code below to write your data to CSV file

> import java.io.FileWriter;
>   import java.io.IOException;
>
> String ID = vars.get("ticketid");
>
> //Change the file path below
>       FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("F:\test_20140529.csv", true);
>
> ```
> if (ID != "")
> {
> writer.append(ID);
> writer.append('\n');
> writer.flush();
> }
> writer.close();`
> ```

- Use CSV Data Set Config, use "test_20140526.csv" created.
- pass CSV data as parameters for the next request.

Hope this will help.